# Writing to a texture from fragment shader (HLSL)

Tags: hlsl, unity-webgl, compute-shader

I'm working on an Unity game (I'm new here) with WebGL as a target platform. I wanted to use Compute Shader to calculate an texture, however WebGL does not support Compute Shaders yet.

So... What else can I use?

I wanted to try using a fragment shader. In GLSL there is an option to write to texture using [Image Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) (not supported in WebGL too). I have also tried to move to CPU, but the performance is very poor this way.

Any hint would be appreciated!

EDIT: I thought in HLSL it's "Pixel shader", fixed to "Fragment Shader"

Comment: You were right that it's "Pixel Shader" in HLSL :) Regarding your question: Have you tried any of the RW-types (RWTexture, etc)? If they aren't supported, then I'm afraid you're out of luck and have to find a way to implement what you want by just using regular shading